# Iptables - Routing is happening before OUTPUT Chain when it involves loopback traffic

Tags: networking, iptables, redhat, keepalived

I am implementing a High Availability (HA) service with keepalived (VRRP). This HA is supposed to work only for the application running on port 443, so we are not failing over the whole server, instead, only the application should fail over.

For this to work, I have to force all the servers in the subnet to send data to the Virtual IP (VIP) instead of the real server IP, when the requested port is 443. For this example, imagine the following:

**Primary Server - private IP: 10.101.151.59**
**Secondary Server - private IP: 10.101.151.9**
**Virtual IP Valid for both servers: 10.101.251.120**

In order to **force** communication to the VIP, when traffic is going to port 443, I have been using the following rule for each of the servers in the subnet:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 10.101.151.59 --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.101.251.120:443;
```

This rule works fine when the *VIP is not owned by the server initiating the request*. However, imagine this situation where the rule is not working:

*1) The application crashes on the primary server. 

2) Fail-over happens and the secondary server starts to receive/handle requests and it will own the VIP.*

If this application now running on secondary server tries to communicate to itself, **it will raise a request to the real IP of the primary server, because this IP is gathered automatically through name resolution**.

In theory, I would expect this traffic to match the iptables rule defined above.
 
However, once the VIP is owned by the secondary server itself, Iptables would have to translate the real IP to one of the local IPs of the server, which would involve loopback. The problem is that it simply does not work.

In practice, traffic is really going to the Primary server and seems this rule is never activated. Since the Primary server is down, I just get Connection Refused.

So the question is: *Why I am not seeing the effect of this rule when the destination VIP belongs to the same server that initiated the request? Is it because loopback may be involved in this communication? would this matter if loopback is involved?*

I know that all traffic initiated by the FW HOST will cross OUTBOUND chain, so not sure why this is not happening, apparently routing is happening first. I read that the kernel may block re-routing of local traffic, so I tried the following:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1
```

But it was not enough. Am I missing anything?

I am using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago).

Thanks. If the question is not clear, let me know.

Comment: Traffic only hits the OUTPUT chain when the kernel knows for sure that the traffic is to leave the system; this can only be known *after* routing. I don't understand why you're using iptables to manage een virtual IP, with keepalived managing the VIP it should be enough to just send traffic to the VIP always.

Comment: So Wurtel, I can't send traffic to VIP always. There are other applications using this same server, but they are not part this HA setup. Therefore, I just want to send traffic to VIP when the Destination Port is 443. I don't know another way of doing it since I have this restriction of just using HA for port 443. Also, application should use the server name, I can't hardcode IPs on the application, it should trust on either DNS or entry on hosts file.